# Construction difficulties with “en voir” + preposition

Tags: prépositions

At the end of French paragraph, I had this sentence, which was marked as 'unclear' by my teacher:

> Je n'en ai pas vu assez à savoir c'est comme.

I did accidentally omit the *ce qui* part from what it is like below, because I was rushing, but I was intending to say:

> I haven't seen enough of it to know what it's like.

In the construction of:

> Je [I] n'en ai pas vu assez [have not (n'en + ai + pas) seen (vu) enough of it (en - before)]
>
> à savoir [to know] ce qui [what] c'est comme [it's like]

I made some other attemps, but are any of these better? I actually think the preposition should be *de* or *pour* instead of *à*.

> Je n'en ai pas vu assez de savoir ce qui c'est comme
>
> Je n'en ai pas vu assez pour savoir ce qui c'est comme

Comment: In your original sentence *I haven't seen enough of it to know what it's like* what is *it* referring to? It would help us give you the best answer...

Comment: @Alexis Pigeon - une église - so it would probably be `elle`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With *ce qui*, the sentence would not really make sense, either “*Je n'en ai pas vu assez à savoir c'est comme ce qui*” or “*Je n'en ai pas vu assez pour savoir ce qui c'est comme*” or any variation actually.

Here *c'est comme* for *it's like* is too litteral, you have to use “*ça ressemble à …*” or a synonym like “*ça a l'air de …*” instead.
So since you're talking about a church : “*Je n'en ai pas vu assez pour savoir de quoi elle a l'air*” assuming the church has been mentioned before.

Or maybe slightly better, a bit more idiomatic, I think : “*Je ne l'ai pas assez bien vue pour savoir à quoi elle ressemble*”.

Comment: It has already been mentioned before, so I think I will use 'Je n'en ai pas vu assez pour savoir de quoi elle à l'air'. Merci

Answer (score 2):

The first part of your sentence is correct, up to "assez". Then you should use "pour" to translate "to":

- Je n'en ai pas vu assez pour savoir...

To translate "what it's like", I would prefer the shortest version: "comment c'est". Other options that keep the notion of "it's like" are "à quoi ça ressemble", "de quoi ça a l'air".

So the complete sentence would be:

- Je n'en ai pas vu assez pour savoir comment c'est.

Answer (score -2):

You must say « Je n'ai pas vu assez pour savoir à quoi ça ressemble. »

Comment: `Je n'ai pas vu assez...` (de) quoi ? Il manque un bout :-(